# How to Filter Checkboxes with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox, filter

I am trying to get these three sections of checkboxes to filter with Angular and am a little lost at this point. The following is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been messing with this for a day and a half.

```js
var filterMod = angular.module('angularNav', [])
.controller('angularController', function($scope) {
  //sample data
  var tags = [];
  var program1 = {
    name:'By Program',
    properties: [
      {name:'By Program',value:'Financial Inclusion'}, {name:'By Program',value:'Education and Learning'},
      {name:'By Program',value:'Youth Livelihoods'}, {name:'By Program',value:'Scholars Program'}, 
    ]
  };
  var program2 = {
    name:'By Region',
    properties:[
      {name:'By Region',value:'Sub-Saharan Africa'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Benin'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Burkina Faso'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Burundi'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Cameroon'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Cote dIvoir'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Democratic Republic of the Congo'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Djibouti'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Ethiopia'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Ghana'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Kenya'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Madagascar'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Malawi'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Mauritius'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Mozambique'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Liberia'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Rwanda'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Uganda'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Senegal'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'South Africa'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Tanzania'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Togo'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Zambia'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Zimbabwe'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Northern Africa'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Egypt'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Morocco'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Northern America'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Canada'}, {name:'By Region',value:'United States of America'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Latin America and the Caribbean'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Columbia'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Costa Rica'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Dominican Republic'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Guatemala'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Honduras'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Haiti'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Paraguay'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Peru'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Asia'}, {name:'By Region',value:'Lebanon'},
      {name:'By Region',value:'Nepal'}

    ]
  };
  var program3 = {
    name:'By Theme',
    properties: [
      {name:'By Theme',value:'Agriculture'}, {name:'By Theme',value:'Women'},
      {name:'By Theme',value:'Young People'}, {name:'By Theme',value:'Leadership'},
      {name:'By Theme',value:'Research and Learning'}, {name:'By Theme',value:'Technology'}
    ]
  };
  
  tags.push(program1);
  tags.push(program2);
  tags.push(program3);    
    
  $scope.Program = tags;
  
  //create checkbox filters on the fly
  var filters = [];
  _.each(tags, function(program){
    _.each(program.properties,function(property){      
      var existingfilter = _.findWhere(filters, { name: property.name });
        if(!existingfilter){
        var filter = {};
        filter.name = property.name;
        filter.values = [];
        filter.values.push({value: property.value});
        filters.push(filter);   
      }else{
        var existingoption = _.findWhere(existingfilter.values, { value: property.value });
        if(!existingoption){
           existingfilter.values.push({value: property.value}); 
        }
      }   
    });
  });
  $scope.Filters = filters;
  
});
  
filterMod.filter('dynamicFilter', function () {
  return function (tags, filterCategories, scope) {
    var filtered = [];
    
    var programFilters = _.filter(filterCategories, function(fc) {
      return  _.any(fc.values, { 'IsIncluded': true });
    });
    
    _.each(tags, function(prog) {
      var includeProgram = true;
      _.each(programFilters, function(filter) {
        var props = _.filter(prog.properties, { 'name': filter.name });
        if (!_.any(props, function(prog) { return _.any(filter.values, { 'value': prog.value, 'IsIncluded': true }); })){
          includeProgram = false;
        }
      });
      if (includeProgram) {
        filtered.push(prog);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

```css
.ng-cloak{
  display:none;
}
.topnav{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
}

.program{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:20px;
  padding:20px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#eee;
}
.sortoptions{
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:0px;
}
h3{
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
ul{
  margin-top:2px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>MCF Nav Filter</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div ng-app='angularNav' class="ng-cloak" ng-cloak="">
  <div ng-controller="angularController">
    <h2>Tag Filters</h2>
    <div class="topnav">
      <div ng-repeat="filter in Filters">
          <h3 class="sort">{{filter.name}}</h3>
          <ul class="sortoptions">
            <li ng-repeat="option in filter.values">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.IsIncluded"  ng-checked="option.IsIncluded"> {{option.value}}
            </li>

          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="programlist">
      <div ng-repeat="program in Programs | dynamicFilter:Filters:this" class="program">
        {{program.name}}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/angular.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js'></script>

  <script src="js/test.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you create a plunker and specify the problem?

Comment: I haven't used Plunker before so I think this is it http://plnkr.co/edit/ZEoQXf21kfWw9aL6jv6O

Comment: @idiosyncratic had to change `css/style.css` to just `style.css` and `js/script.js` to just `script.js` to get your Plunkr to run. Corrected Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hDfoHymV5DeB9ZOKI01u?p=preview). There's more errors in the console, so this might not be everything

Comment: Thank you for fixing that as I haven't used it before. That is the way it is supposed to look. My problem is getting it to filter and show results. I am completely stumped on that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you are trying to filter here.  All the data is already on the screen.  Are you just trying to show, beneath all the checkboxes, the list of selected checkbox items?

Comment: Agree with @Scott 's question. However, I did just notice in your HTML you have `ng-repeat="program in Programs | dynamicFilter:Filters:this"` but there is no `$scope.Programs` defined or accessed anywhere in your JS. Did you mean to use `$scope.Program`? Changing your HTML to be `program in Program` made some more things show up in the page, but I'm still not clear what your goal is

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the checked items to show. I got this far and had no idea how to move forward and get it all to filter and show correctly.

Comment: Ok, I changed the $scope.Programs but now all of my data is gone and I am left with three boxes. I would like the original data to show and then if I click a checkbox in the Program category and another checkbox in the Region and another in the Theme it will filter correctly.

Comment: In my plunkr, changing it to `$scope.Program` showed both the checkboxes and those 3 boxes

Comment: See it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XTvbGq6hDLW4KNKl7PEN?p=preview). From here, what is it you want it to do? When you select a checkbox, you want that to show up in one of those boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the way you are doing the entire thing is a bit wonky. But to get it working with what you have just use this instead of your ng-repeat program in Programs

```
    <div ng-repeat="filterItem in Filters" class="program">
      <div ng-repeat="item in filterItem.values | filter:{IsIncluded:true}">
        {{item.value}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I replaced the code but it isn't working and only shows the three boxes with no data.

Comment: Here is the working Plunker. You had not replaced the correct code. http://plnkr.co/edit/ipqNBQiMFZqGKyVIOuzH?p=preview